# Relation between two classes

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have a class A (dispatcher) that deals with the communication and parsing of received data and should pass it to class B (business logic of the application).

Class B and class A should call each other because the communication is two-way:
sending data from the business logic layer and receiving data as responses.

Any suggestions for the best design that can be used to facilitate the communications between class A and B. I don't think that they should just point to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a long running operation, you can think about implementing those operations as pair of `BeginOperation()` and `EndOperation()` methods, use callbacks or some other async pattern (check [Asynchronous Programming Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)).

I'd also avoid circular references. I would implement this in a similar manner to WCF Duplex services. In project B create your business class B, and interface which would represent a contract that other projects need to implement in order to be called back from B, lets call it IBCallbackContract. So you'd need to:

1. Create class B
2. Create `IBCallbackContract`
3. Create `Initialize(IBCallbackContract)` method which would take callback objects
4. Create class A which makes use of BL class
5. Implement `IBCallbackContract` in project A, let's call it `BLCallback`
6. On startup of A, create an instance of `BLCallback`
7. Call `Initialize` method of B, sending it the instance of `BLCallback`

Comment: When I get something from the communication (class A) then I need to path is to the BL (Class B) .But sometimes BL need to send data to the class A, not related to some calls just send it to the communication level.

Comment: You don't have a lot of choice then. Either you're going to create callbacks, or have a indirect circular reference, through proxy in shared project. I'd personally go for callback because circular references terrify me when I think of what a tangled mess such project can become. I edited my suggestions in answer.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to send information using a method on class B and receive data using an event on class B. When you start, class A subscribes to the event and the two way communication will now work.